Why did it fail when trying to connect to a Neo4j database in Python using PythonAnywhere?
I wrote a simple Python script to connect to my Neo4j database instance and retrieve some data using the official Neo4j library. I am trying to run this script on PythonAnywhere, but it failed to connect to the database, printing "Unable to retrieve routing information." The URI, username, and password are correct; it successfully connects to the database from my desktop application written in Java.
Here is the full script in Python:
from neo4j import GraphDatabase


URI = "neo4j+s://uri:7687"
AUTH = ("usn", "pwd")

class PlayersNeo4jDatabaseManager:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(URI, auth=AUTH)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def get_players_query(self, tx):
        query = "MATCH (p:Player) RETURN p LIMIT 1;"
        players = tx.run(query)
        for player in players:
            print(player)

    def get_players(self):
        with self.driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
            session.read_transaction(self.get_players_query)

playersNeo4jDatabaseManager = PlayersNeo4jDatabaseManager()
playersNeo4jDatabaseManager.get_players()

I tried neo4j://, neo4j+ssc, and bolt, but it did not work.

I don't see how tags "java" and "neo4jclient" are relevant. Can you explain?

Java because I tried the connection in a Java desktop application.

Your problem is with connecting from Python, so tag [tag:java] is not relevant. I've removed it.

I replaced neo4jclient with neo4j-python-driver.

Free accounts cannot connect out of PythonAnywhere except using http(s) through the proxy. So database connections will not work from a free account. If you upgrade to a paid account, that restriction is removed.

The connection to a Neo4j database on PythonAnywhere may fail due to network restrictions or firewall settings blocking the connection. PythonAnywhere typically doesn't allow outbound connections to external services like databases. To resolve this, ensure the Neo4j instance is accessible over a public IP and configure PythonAnywhere's outbound connection settings accordingly.

And can you please tell me how to configure PythonAnywhere's outbound connection settings?
